# Is Mastery of Baby Rudin ch.6 Sufficient Pre-requisite knowledge for Daddy Rudin ch.1?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, self-learning

I intend on taking a Measure-Theoretic Probability course in the fall at the level of Rick Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*.

I am self-studying Baby Rudin chapters 1-7 this summer, and I am currently on chapter 6. I am asking the following:

If I have an **excellent** understanding of Baby Rudin ch.6 (on the Riemann-Stieltjes integral), **is this sufficient pre-requisite knowledge for Daddy Rudin ch.1?**

Comment: Finish up Chapter 7 of Baby Rudin and you're probably good to start on Daddy.

Comment: IMHO Rudin's books are not good for self-study, they are better for specific consults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edit: I missed the part about **Chapter 1** of Big Rudin. My answer is yes, study Chapter 7 of Baby Rudin. Sequences of functions figure prominently in Chapter 1. Chapters 8 and 9 might not be necessary right away, but you will need them for probability anyway. The answer below assumed you intended to go further in Big Rudin.)

You might be able to get by, because there are few hard prerequisites, but in terms of mathematical maturity, I can't imagine studying much of Big Rudin without knowing most of the material from Chapters 7-9. It's okay if you've studied it elsewhere.

- Ideas about uniform convergence (Chapter 7 of Baby Rudin) come up regularly in Big Rudin. Even more complicated variations on this idea appear, so it's best to be comfortable with the basics.
- Power series (Chapter 8) come up in complex analysis, obviously. I don't recall offhand if they come up before then, but this is important background knowledge for anyone.
- The positive results on pointwise convergence of Fourier series in Chapter 8 of Baby Rudin are important background knowledge for the negative results in Chapter 5 of Big Rudin. It would be a bit strange to read things on Fourier series in Big Rudin without having studied this.
- Differential calculus (Chapter 9) is necessary even to understand the statement of the change-of-variable formula, let alone its proof.

So the answer depends on your prior knowledge of analysis. But assuming you don't know Chapters 7-9 from elsewhere, I would say that you'd have to have some good reason to want to dive into Big Rudin first.

Even with respect to probability, all of these topics are important.

Comment: This is very helpful advice. Thank you.

Comment: Chapter 10 (and its exercises) are pretty obviously divided into two halves: the part up to Theorem 10.9 and the part after that. The theory in the first half will be redone anyway when you learn about Lebesgue integration (going up to Chapter 8 of Big Rudin), so you can delay it if you want to. But the kinds of computational exercises corresponding to the first half of Chapter 10 aren't repeated. These are important for probability. I hadn't considered this when I wrote my answer,